# View all my posts?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

"All my posts" unavailable? There is only "top posts". An option as basic as this should be there from the beginning. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: The app is very basic, it's meant only to read and write questions. Anything beyond that is a welcome bonus.

Comment: Interestingly, the iOS app *does* offer a link to 'all my posts' (on a specific site).

Comment: @Glorfindel the iOS app is still under development, android app is dead. (i.e. nobody is working on it anymore. To discuss this, better do it [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1054/room-for-shadow-wizard-and-cai))